# correction to the code of mergesort and merge in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
merge ::(ord a) => [a] ->[a] -> [a]
merge [][] = []
merge [a][b] = [[a,b]|a<-mergesort [a],b<- mergesort [b]]

mergesort ::(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
mergesort [] = []
mergesort (x:xs) = if xs >=2 then mergesort xs else mergesort(x:xs)
                                 | comparision > 0 = x:xs
                                 | comparision <= 0 =  xs:x
                                  where comparision = x-xs
```

That is the code what I've written for merge and mergesort and is not right of course.

Could you give some advises to correct the code?
plese don't give me the answers....

Comment: Yikes. There's a *lot* of errors. Covering them all would cover about half the material of a complete Haskell tutorial. Maybe you'd better start with some simpler list-manipulation functions to get some practice with the basics before trying a sorting algorithm. Say, `sum` for adding up all the numbers in a list; `and` for checking if a list has `False` anywhere in it; `length` for finding out how many elements a list has; maybe a specialized `filter` or something that takes a `[Char]` and returns a list of the upper-case characters from it; and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, the only error the compiler gives is this one:

```
test.hs:8:34: error: parse error on input ‘|’
  |
8 |                                  | comparision > 0 = x:xs
  |                                  ^
```

Therefore I will assume this is the one you are stuck on, and talk about how to fix this problem.

The basic issue is that guards (that is, the syntactic form where there's a pipe character `|` followed by a condition) are only allowed at binding sites (like function equations or inside `case` statements). You've included yours at an incorrect position. It's not completely clear what you mean those guards to do, so I'm not too certain how to help you put them in the correct position.

Perhaps the best help I can give is to describe what they mean with some abstract examples, and let you figure out where you want them to go instead. Take this as an example:

```
f x y | cond1 = val1
      | cond2 = val2
      | cond3 = val3
```

This defines a new function named `f`, which takes two arguments. It names the arguments `x` and `y`. Then, to decide what value to return, it checks the guards, looking for the first one that evaluates to `True`. So if `cond1` evaluates to `True`, the function returns `val1`; if `cond1` evaluates to `False` but `cond2` evaluates to `True`, the function returns `val2`; if `cond1` and `cond2` evaluate to `False` but `cond3` evaluates to `True`, the function returns `val3`. (..and if all three conditions evaluate to `False`, it throws a runtime exception.)

Now let's look at the syntax you used:

```
mergesort (x:xs) = if xs >=2 then mergesort xs else mergesort(x:xs)
                                 | comparision > 0 = x:xs
                                 | comparision <= 0 =  xs:x
```

It here you are defining a new function named `mergesort` that accepts one argument. It matches that argument against the pattern `x:xs`. Then it appears to return the result of `if xs >=2 then mergesort xs else mergesort(x:xs)`. But what are these two extra guards doing? I don't know. Perhaps you are imagining that if `comparision > 0`, then the function will return `x:xs` *instead* of `if xs >=2 then ... else ...`. If so, you should write it this way:

```
mergesort (x:xs) | comparision > 0 = x:xs
                 | comparision <= 0 = xs:x
                 | otherwise = if x >=2 then mergesort xs else mergesort(x:xs)
```

Or perhaps you are imagining that if `comparision > 0`, then the recursive call will use `x:xs` instead of `(x:xs)`. If so, you should write it this way:

```
mergesort (x:xs) | comparision > 0 = if x >=2 then mergesort xs else mergesort(x:xs)
                 | comparision <= 0 = if x >=2 then mergesort xs else mergesort(xs:x)
```

I'm not sure what was intended.

Anyway, hopefully this helps you resolve your parse error, and gets you to the point where you can look at the next compiler errors and take a stab at fixing those yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A couple questions to ask yourself:

1. What, specifically, are you trying to do with the functions `merge` and `mergesort`? Suppose I have a list I want sorted -- just one list, not yet split up. Which function should I call to use your implementation of the merge sort?
2. Based on the type signature `mergesort :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, how many arguments should `mergesort` have?
3. What are the types of `x` and `xs`? Are all functions you're applying to variables defined for those types? I see the functions `-`, `:`, `>=`, and `mergesort`. The types given for those functions (except for `mergesort`) by ghci's `:t` are as follows:

   - `(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`. This means:

     1. `(-)` takes two arguments of the same type. This type must belong to the typeclass `Num` -- that is, it must be some kind of number.
     2. `(-)` returns a single value of that type.
   - `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. This means:

     1. `(:)` takes an argument of one type, and another argument that is a *list* of values of that type.
     2. `(:)` returns a list of values of that type.
   - `(>=) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`. This means:

     1. `(>=)` takes two arguments of the same type. This type must belong to the `Ord` typeclass -- that is, it must be possible to compare two values of that type and say that one value is greater than, less than, or equal to the other value. (In `Prelude`, this includes all members of typeclass `Num`.)
     2. `(>=)` returns a `Bool`.

You should also think about how you want to structure your implementation. Think about how the merge sort works. Look at the steps, think about how you can implement those steps as functions, and how you can connect those steps together with one `mergesort` function. Once you have a design planned out, *then* you should worry about the syntax.

Comment: your last advice could also be phrased as "write lots of very short functions first, and use *them* to implement your main function. don't try to write it all out at once. define a separate function for each separate step in your algorithm first."